# Android configuration setup application politics

Tags: java, android, installation

I have made an android app and I have some .csv files with initial data. Can anyone suggest a proper way to do that? For example, someone could say "just create a folder and put them inside" but I want a better way like a setup that I can do with windows (e.g. installshield but no so advanced ).

Answer (score 0):

You can make with wizard forms. In first window choose .csv file, in second window
match the fileds of .csv file with database fildes and finally upload data.

Comment: Just to add files. Only that. Sorry for the confusion with DB.